# TensorFlow. Keras.sequential.fit(x_train, y_train,...)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Needs your help to design a cnn model for text detection. Getting error here when invoking *keras.sequential*.**fit(x_train, y_train,..)**?
I've .txt files with multiple GT annotations for each image, what will be y_train? How these .txt files will be in y_train?

Code related to ground truth (.txt file) is as below :

```
# Upload the training dataset gt from disk
source_train_gt = '/content/sample_data/y_train'
directory = os.scandir(source_train_gt)
y_train_data = np.zeros((20,))
for file in directory:
    gtfile = open(source_train_gt +'/'+ file.name,'r')
    np.append(y_train_data, gtfile)

# My CNN Model
myCNN = Sequential()
myCNN.add(Convolution2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, input_shape = (64,64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
myCNN.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
myCNN.add(Flatten())
myCNN.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
myCNN.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

myCNN.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

# when following fit method is invoked, error is generated:
myCNN.fit(x_train_data, y_train_data, epochs = 10, validation_data = (x_test_data, y_test_data))
```

When invoking fit method, it throws following error :

> Epoch 1/10WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None,
> 64, 64, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 64,
> 64, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input',
> description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'"), but it was called on
> an input with incompatible shape
> (None,).---------------------------------------------------------------------------ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) in
> ()----> 1 myCNN.fit(x_train_data, y_train_data, epochs = 10,
> validation_data = (x_test_data, y_test_data)) 1
> frames/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py
> in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)   1127 except Exception as e: #
> pylint:disable=broad-except   1128 if hasattr(e,
> "ag_error_metadata"):-> 1129 raise
> e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)   1130 else:   1131 raise
> ValueError: in user code:
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 878, in train_function *        return step_function(self,
> iterator)    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 867, in step_function **        outputs =
> model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 860, in run_step **        outputs = model.train_step(data)   
> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
> line 808, in train_step        y_pred = self(x, training=True)    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py",
> line 67, in error_handler        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb)
> from None    File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py",
> line 227, in assert_input_compatibility        raise
> ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
>     ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).        Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible
> with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=1. Full shape
> received: (None,)        Call arguments received:      •
> inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=float32)      • training=True   
>   • mask=None

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously problem is with your input data shape. `Conv2D` expects input hape 4D. but you giving 1D.

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras as keras

X_train = np.random.random((2356,64,64,3))
y_train = np.random.random((2356, 1))

myCNN = tf.keras.Sequential()
myCNN.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, input_shape = (64,64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
myCNN.add(keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = 2))
myCNN.add(keras.layers.Flatten())
myCNN.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
myCNN.add(keras.layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

myCNN.compile(optimizer = 'adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy'])

# when following fit method is invoked, error is generated:
myCNN.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 15)
```

**Output**

```
poch 1/15
74/74 [==============================] - 14s 9ms/step - loss: 0.8949 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6775 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.6103 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5413 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.5157 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 6/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5067 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 7/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.5030 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 8/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5029 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 9/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5030 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 10/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5036 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 11/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5065 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 12/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5054 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 13/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 0.5031 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 14/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 9ms/step - loss: 0.5025 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 15/15
74/74 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 0.5025 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```